# server and multiple clients using pthreads and select()

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, pthreads

consider the next piece of code -

```
int get_ready_connection(int s) {
    /* socket of connection */
    int caller;
    if ((caller = accept(s,NULL,NULL)) < SUCCESS)
    {
        server_log->write_to_log(sys_call_error(SERVER, "accept"));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    return caller;
}


int establish_connection(sockaddr_in& connection_info)
{
    // Create socket
    if ((server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < SUCCESS)
    {
        server_log->write_to_log(sys_call_error(SERVER, "socket"));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    // Bind `sock` with given addresses
    if (bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &connection_info, \
             sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < SUCCESS)
    {
        close(server_sock);
        server_log->write_to_log(sys_call_error(SERVER, "bind"));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    // Max # of queued connects
    if (listen(server_sock, MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS) < SUCCESS)
    {
        server_log->write_to_log(sys_call_error(SERVER, "listen"));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a set of file descriptors and empty it.
    fd_set set;
    bool is_inside;
    int ret_val;

    while(true)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&set);

        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &set);
        FD_SET(server_sock, &set);

        struct timeval tv = {2, 0};

        ret_val = select(server_sock + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &tv); // TODO ret_val

        is_inside = FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &set);
        if(is_inside)
        {
            // get user input
            string user_input;
            getline(cin, user_input);

            if ((strcasecmp(user_input.c_str(), EXIT_TEXT) == 0))
            {
                return SUCCESS;
            }
        }

        is_inside = FD_ISSET(server_sock, &set);
        if(is_inside)
        {
            // get the first connection request
            int current_connection = get_ready_connection(server_sock);
            if (current_connection == FAILURE) {
                free_allocated_memory();
                exit_write_close(server_log, sys_call_error(SERVER, "accept"),
                                 ERROR);
            }

            // if exit was not typed by the server's stdin, process the request
            pthread_t thread;

            // create thread
            if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, command_thread_func, &current_connection) != 0)
            {
                free_allocated_memory();
                exit_write_close(server_log, sys_call_error(SERVER, "pthread_create"), ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All im trying to do, is to "listen" to STDIN for the user to type 'EXIT' in server's shell, and to wait for clients to pass commands from their shells (every time a command is recieved by the server from the user, the server parses it, and the server creates a thread that handles execution of the command)
To do it simultaniously, i used select().

When i work with a single thread, everything's perfect. But the problem is when im connecting another client i get a seg fault. i suspect that the problem is right here. any suggestions?

Comment: This is not answerable without the code of `command_thread_func`. Also, [please provide an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I suggest you run your program in a debugger and when it crashes, tell the debugger to print a stack trace showing the exact line where the crash occurred.  That will be very helpful in figuring out why the crash happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know if this is your exact problem, but this is definitely *a* problem:

You can't call `pthread_create` and provide a pointer to a stack variable (`&current_connection`) as your thread function's argument. For one thing, it's subject to immediate destruction as soon as the parent exits that scope.

Secondly, it will be overwritten on the next call to `get_ready_connection`.